# перенаправление C HTTP на HTTPS в контейнерах docker

Tags: nginx, http, docker, https, config

у меня следющая проблема:
Есть 2 докер контейнера, 2fa-nginx и 2fa-cabinet.

2fa-nginx это nginx, который проксирует с других контенеров на https://example.com/

2fa-cabinet также nginx, который просто запускает на htts://example.com/ кабиенет (так же у него есть адрес на локальном уровне, "http://2fa-cabinet:80")

Задача в том чтобы настроить 2fa-nginx так, чтобы он на серверном уровне брал http://2fa-cabinet:80
и стримил его на https://example.com/cabinet

вот конфиг 2fa-nginx:

```
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx/files/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/nginx/files/localhost.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://2fa-flask:80;
    location /sett/ {
      proxy_pass http://2fa-settings:80;
    }
}
```

Вот конфиг 2fa-cabinet:

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    acess_log on;
    acess log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    index index.html
  }
```

у меня уже настроено несколько форвардов с контейнерами 2fa-flask, 2fa-settings, но они не являются отдельными nginx'ми, а 2fa-cabinet это отдельный nginx. Прошу вас помочь мне с этим.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить проксирование запросов с https://example.com/cabinet на http://2fa-cabinet:80 добавьте в конфиг 2fa-nginx location:

```
    location /cabinet/ {
      proxy_pass http://2fa-cabinet;
    }
```